# How to scroll vertically to a line, in HTML automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im not sure I can describe this well. I want to put an element to the HTML content which will automatic ask the browser to scroll there vertically, when its loaded. Like an anchor. So:

```
| visible area |
| content html |
| content html |        our monitor
| content html |
| content html |
----------------
|
|
| * here comes the HTML element which will ask the browser to scroll here
|
|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 200}, 1000);
}
```

not tested so let me know if it wont work

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scrolldiv = $('#content');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(scrolldiv).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

scrolldiv will be the your element that wraps the content html;